# Google chrome shows ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when accessing website after HTTPS is enabled

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4, ubuntu-18.04

I have a webpage hosted from a Google Compute Engine, with Apache 2.4 installed. I can access the page at, for example, `http://1.2.3.4/` ok. Now I want to enable SSL. I have followed two similar tutorials [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-18-04) and [here](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/configure-apache-with-tls-ssl-certificate-on-ubuntu-18/). To summarize what I did:

1. Create cert `.crt` and key `.key` files.
2. Edit the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` by changing `ServerName` to `1.2.3.4`, then changing `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` to the cert and key files in step 1.
3. Edit the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` in the block `<VirtualHost *:80>` to have the same `ServerName` as the IP, then replicate that block but with different port as `<VirtualHost *:443>`
4. Allow Apache profile in the firewall with this command `sudo ufw allow 'Apache Full'`
5. Enable ssl mod with `sudo a2enmod ssl`, then enable the config with `sudo a2ensite default-ssl.conf`
6. Restart the server `sudo service apache2 restart`

In Chrome, when I access `https://1.2.3.4/` or `https://1.2.3.4:443/`, it shows something like:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection
>
> 1.2.3.4 sent an invalid response.
>
> Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
>
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Here is the content of my `000-default.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 1.2.3.4
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/usename/mypage
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName 1.2.3.4
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/usename/mypage
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Accessing the `http` link is still ok (I did not redirect the HTTP traffic to HTTPS). How do I make https work? (My Google Compute Engine is Ubuntu 18.04.3)

Comment: Does `ServerName` in the certificate that you created match the one in conf file?

Comment: @mazaneicha yes, I put in the same IP address of the google vm

Comment: @Pandurang I added `SSLEngine On` in `000-default.conf` and the server couldn't even start. But removing that line then it works again.  Please put a proper answer with steps to do, which files to edit. Thanks